# Rails - passing local variable to partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have view, which render users of my app. I want to make partial, which consists necessary fields, and pass to it local variable

users/index

```
- @vk = VkontakteApi::Client.new
- fields = [:first_name, :last_name, :url, :photo_medium, :sex, :bdate]

- @vk.friends.get(uid: current_user.uid, fields: fields) do |friend|
  %td.span
    .centred
      = render 'shared/users', locals: { friend: friend }
```

shared/users

```
- @vk = VkontakteApi::Client.new
- fields = [:first_name, :last_name, :url, :photo_medium, :sex, :bdate]

%span= image_tag friend.photo_medium
%span= friend.uid
%span= friend.name
```

But if i try it there is an error

```
undefined local variable or method `friend'
```

Thanks! If you need more information, please comment about it

Comment: what line does the error reference?

Comment: = image_tag friend.photo_medium

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
= render partial: 'shared/users', locals: { friend: friend }
```

or the shorthand:

```
= render 'shared/users', friend: friend
```